# SQL Query performance difference between Wordpress and PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, query-performance

I am hosting a wordpress site on with a shared hosting provider (Hostgator), and am experiencing some significant performance issues that I can't really explain.

Any database query takes an order of magnitude longer to run from Wordpress than it takes from phpMyAdmin.
An example is a simple options query:

```
SELECT option_value 
FROM heenakim_options 
WHERE option_name = 'nkweb_track_login_and_register' 
LIMIT 1
```

Using MySQL Profiler plugin for Wordpress I see that this takes 0.15638614 seconds to execute.
If I now log on to PhpMyAdmin and execute the same query, it takes 0.004 seconds to complete.

Now this isn't an enourmously slow query, but add up all the queries I have (alot) and the page easily takes 10-20 seconds to load. All queries I test are consistently 30-100 times slower when run via php and Wordpress.

Is this normal? I've seen the Profiler plugin show sites where the same type of query takes less than 0.05 seconds to execute, so it can't just be profiler overhead (I think). The database connects through localhost from the web site, so web and DB servers should be hosted on the same machine, possibly adding CPU but data transfer should be negligible (and the query above doesn't return any results anyways).

My options table isn't massive either, have about 230 records in it. I have cleaned and optimised the database, so that shouldn't make any difference either, but on the other hand then I should have seen the performance degradation from PhpMyAdmin as well.

Does anyone have a good idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is the table indexed?

Comment: *"it can't just be profiler overhead"* I think so.

Comment: can you show how you are querying from php? Maybe it's just bad usage of the results / Query classes?

Comment: I've checked the tables and they have the standard Wordpress indexes, the _options table has a unique index on option_name.

Comment: I'm using the standard way of querying from Wordpress, (as these queries originate among others from the core framework)

Comment: Are you using get_option or your own query?

Comment: I'm using get_option (or the theme I am using seem to be calling a number of options using it that doesn't exist).